# Wrong width for certain characters

Tags: options, unicode, encoding

Using this:

https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/releases/download/v8.2.1505/gvim_8.2.1505_x64.zip

All of these characters (and perhaps others):

## ℹ ⌨ ⏏ ⏭ ⏮ ⏯ ⏱ ⏲ ⏸ ⏹ ⏺ ☀ ☁ ☂ ☃ ☄ ☎ ☑ ☝ ☠

## ☠️ ☢ ☣ ☦ ☪ ☮ ☯ ☸ ☹ ♟ ♨ ♻ ♾ ⚒ ⚔ ⚕ ⚕️ ⚖ ⚖️ ⚗

## ⚙ ⚛ ⚜ ⚠ ⚰ ⚱ ⛈ ⛏ ⛩ ⛰ ⛱ ⛴ ⛷ ⛸ ✂ ✈ ✈️ ✉ ✍ ✏

## ✒ ✔ ✖ ✝ ✡ ✳ ✴ ❄ ❇ ❣ ❤ ❤️ ➡

are "single width" instead of "double width". This causes overlapping and other
problems. I notice if I open the same file in Windows Notepad, output is
correct. Is some option available to fix this?